# HTML5 Video Best Practice

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I have a lot of video on my webpage. I noticed that some of them load very slowly. I think the reason is the resolution.

How can I speed up the loading of my video? What are your the past experience with html5 video settings? Which video resolution, frequency rate and so on should I use? Is there an advantage if I use a video player like VideoJS instead of default HTML5 player?

I would be grateful for every snippet of advice!

Comment: Re-locate the moov atom to the beginning of the file: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

(Creator of video.js here)  what you’d benefit from is a multi bitrate adaptive streaming strategy, creating smaller resolutions of the file for lower bandwidths, helping it always start quickly.  You could use video.js with the HLS plug-in, or HLS.JS with the bare video tag. You’d get similar results between them. FFmpeg and any of the encoding services can create HLS files and manifests to support this approach. It does mean hosting more files per video. Mux.com can also help with this at scale, but I’m one of the founders so take that into account.